# divs on the same line OR one above the other

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to solve this problem in Internet Explorer 8.

I have two `div` tags whose content should be shown on the same line. I know I can easily achieve this by using  `inline-block`. However, I also want that, if the browser window is reduced to the point where the content doesn't fit in a line anymore, the content of the second `div` is moved on the line below.

Basically I'm looking for a behaviour of the kind "show both items on the same line if there is enough space, otherwise go to the next one".

Is there any way to achieve this with IE8? Even a Javascript solution is fine.

Comment: `inline-block` is working for me: http://jsbin.com/hagave/1/edit Please provide an online example to demonstrate the issue in action.

Comment: *"show both items on the same line if there is enough space, otherwise go to the next one"* - That's pretty much the behavior of `inline-block`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `style="float:left"` on both divs. You may need to wrap both of them in another `div` to get the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a media query to check the width of the screen and change the styling based on that:

```
@media(min-width:768px) { //div style here }
```

Check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/b9ahqnt0/

Comment: I didn't know about this! Unfortunalely it's not supported in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

as well as float left try adding a percentage as a width so when the size of the screen is reduced it can adjust. Although normally when it comes to responsive sites you are better setting it up then adjust the issues as Daniel said using @media conditions to change the layout as the screen changes to what you need it to look like..